# Is it a bad idea to generate private keys (certs) at server side?

Tags: c#, windows, security, transfer, private-key

I'm working with some encryption project (using C#) and there is a task, which I'm thinking how to do well.

I need client to generate private keys for asymmetric encryption, but as I have reviewed some libraries, it's NOT such clean & easy task.

Why?

For generating private keys in Windows, I have the next possibilities:

- generate them using `makecert.exe`, `pvk2pfx.exe` etc... but these tools
  are from Windows SDK and seems to be they're linked with other DLLs,
  so if client have a clean OS (without any installed library) I may:
  1). Install Windows SDK on client's PC 2). Copy `makecert.exe` and other utilities and
  hold it with the project distribution (I think, it's a bad idea due different Windows versions (from 7 to 10) and 32/64 bits architecture
- generate using `Bouncy Castle`, not bad way (also I can use programming language and NOT external tools, which is an advantage for me), but the C# version isn't documented well and there are some ugly places in source code
- using `OpenSSL`, don't like it, because there are several functions call
  with errors in library, itself (with multithreading)
- using `PowerShell` (also an option, but I suppose there would be
  problems with supporting it on the old version of Windows like 7)

Due those facts, I suppose, what if I free the client from generating private keys? Is it a bad idea? I can generate it at server side and **DON'T SAVE** private keys at it, just transfer via TLS.

Which secure vulnerabilities exist with a such way? Consider, that use of TLS is the **STRICT** option.

Comment: Why not generate with .NET (RSACryptoServiceProvider)?

Comment: @Evk If it's .NET and only for Windows, so my answer is yes. But what if a client is an Android, iOS based device? Also, the Q is rather about different stuff. About is it secure to do such a transfer with all described options (not saving at backend & strictly via TLS)?

Comment: Depends on what you use there. If you use mono (xamarin) - same RSACryptoServiceProvider should be available there.

Comment: No doubt Android and iOS have their own libraries for this sort of stuff.  But that's really a separate question.  (If you just want to ask whether it is OK to generate the certificates server-side, rather than how to generate them client-side, that should probably be on Information Security Stack Exchange rather than here.)

Comment: @downvoter-hater, Hello!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your application. There are at least couple of issues with generating private key on server.

1. Client must trust you are not saving this key for later. You know that you don't but client does not know that. Depending on application it might be important distinction.
2. Even if you send key over TLS, it still can be intercepted by man in the middle under certain circumstances. For example, company might install trusted root certificate on each computer in organization, then intercept and decrypt all ssl traffic which goes in\out this organisation. Again that might or might not be important depending on the type of your application.

Suppose that you write chat application targeted at large audience, and want to encrypt all messages between users. Then if you will generate keys on server - no one will (or at least should) use your application. First you can dump all their keys to government\whatever (they cannot be 100% sure this cannot happen), and even if you won't do that - there are whole countries where ssl traffic is inspected by using "fake" trusted root certificates.

So long story short - if you can generate private keys on client - do that. In your case I think you can.

Comment: Good answer, thanks! I thought, that TLS is defending against MiT-attack, earlier... :(

Comment: But, maybe there is an option to use TLS mutual authentication, when client need to send certificate too, which server-side will be able to check.

Comment: But then you already have private key on client (that one in certificate) and you don't need to generate it :) If you already have private key on client then I think you can safely deliver more to him.

Comment: There could be several certificates for different aims, first of all. For example, pre-initialized state. OK, thanks, I think I should make some research.

Comment: Just a note: you cannot for example embed client certificate into application and use one for all - then anyone can download your application and extract it. Client certificate should be generated on client and you are back to your problem.

Comment: I'm saving private keys on smart-card (Mifare DESfire EV1), not embedding them into application.

Comment: Well my point is just that mutual TLS won't help, regardless of where you store your keys.

Comment: "If you already have private key on client then I think you can safely deliver more to him": *if* you are also using that key as a client certificate *or* do a signature that includes the server certificate you were presented. Right? See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26145/232.

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon multiple considerations!

- What do your users expect?  Designs that aim to provide "zero-knowledge" solutions such as [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/features/zero-knowledge) guarantee that not even a person with full admin access to the server can decrypt your data.  In this case, generating the key on the server and promising that you do not store it doesn't cut it: anybody with full admin access to the server could break that promise any time.  So to achieve real zero-knowledge, you would have to generate keys on client side.
- Are you willing to accept the performance impact?  Does it open DoS vectors?  Maybe because I am a security guy, I absolutely would not be doing it on the server.

If I were you, I would be pursuing BouncyCastle on client side.